# Transformation of finite measure

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \delta_{x_i}$ is a discrete probability measure. Let $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n$ be such that $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i\beta_i=1$, then $\nu=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i\beta_i \,\delta_{x_i}$ is another discrete probability measure. I am wondering if there is a way to write $\nu$ as a transformation of $\mu$ (i.e. as a convolution with another measure, or through some other concept which is relatively well-studied)?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)$ be Borel measurable nonnegative. Then $\int_A fd\mu=\sum_{1\leq k \leq n}f(x_k)\alpha_k\delta_{x_k}(A)$. We may set $f(x_k)=\beta_k$, zero elsewhere. Then we have found that $f$ is a probability density wrt the discrete probability measure $\mu$, because $\nu(A)=\int_A fd\mu$ is a probability measure.